# How to find the voltage drop in this circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis

For the following circuit, what equations do I have to use to get \$v_0\$? I have tried using Kirchhoff's voltage law, but I am only able to get 3 equations whereas I have 4 unknowns.

I am only looking for guidance.

[image]

Comment: One of those 100 ohm resistors can be removed. Can you see which one? Visual inpection will tell you that the output voltage is zero.

Comment: What do you mean, removed? My intuition would tell me the one between the 5V source and v0, but I wouldn't be able to explain why... @Andyaka

Comment: if you pull out each 1 , if nothing changes on Vo... then you have 3 eqn

Comment: If you are using KVL equations then you are basically using the mesh current method....take a look at that. On the other hand, there are more than four loops you can use...

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I will look at the mesh current method. I have found more than four loops, but I get redundant equations.

Comment: = detached, evacuated, dislodged, ejected, eliminated,   excised, expunged, extirpated, extracted or withdrawn

Comment: To find the right problemstilling, choose your ground wisely.  I'd suggest you define the negative side of the 5V supply above as 0V, and redraw accordingly.  That will make it easier...and the answer is trivial.

Comment: @Bee Andy made it *really easy* for you. Why don't you label the explicit node voltages that you can immediately label, by hand. That only leaves ***one*** node to work out. And since you know both the nearby node voltages and there are only two resistors between them, how hard can this be? You don't have to do anything but work out the most basic, simple, resistor divider question. No need for anything more complicated.

Comment: @jonk should I also consider adding ground following Cristobol's suggestion?

Comment: @Bee While that's a good idea, often enough, there's no need for that here. This is a simple divider and can be easily worked out using nothing more than that. Save the idea of assigning a "convenient" ground for more complex problems. This one doesn't require it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Loop and current names]

At loop 1: 10v-200I1-Vo=0

At loop 2: 10v-100I2-5v=0

At loop 3: 5v+100I3+vo=0

Now find the value of I2 from the above equation 2 to and put to rest of equations, you will get same number of equations and variable.

I would suggest to go through the [Article about Mesh Analysis](http://electric-shocks.com/mesh-current-analysis/).

Comment: +1 For remembering super mesh. A lot of people forget about that.